# Localisation issue with Preference In Android

Tags: android, localization, preference

When i switch language from arabic to english or vice versa  all the preferences are clearing automatically.how can i stop this issue so i can preserve my data.I have tried by removing  app name from manifest from application tag  because i am suspecting this while changing the app name itself.any help?

Comment: How are you storing preferences? Could you post the XML and/or Java code?

Comment: i am using normal preference to store values programmatically  not using prefrenceActivity.